# Using PyCharm with the "Getting Started on Heroku with Python" tutorial

Tags: heroku, pycharm

I have worked through the [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) article, everything works as advertised when executed from the command line.

Now I want to use the PyCharm IDE instead of using the console. But how would I start the example program? On the console I simply run "heroku local"; however the PyCharm run configuration expects a Python script, not a binary.

Please advise how to configure PyCharm to use the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to purchase the commercial version of PyCharm, which includes support for Django, which is what the Heroku tutorial is using.

Other solutions would be to use other IDEs that support Django.